# Переполнение в Си

Tags: c, struct

Задача: написать программу на Си, которая выводит сначала все папки в указанной директории, а затем все файлы. Файлы должны выводиться в порядке возрастания размера. Проблема в том, что при обработке второго файла/папки данные начинают портиться (вместо записанных данных в структуре появляется мусор).

Код: https://pastebin.com/h0KGtZgd

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct
{
    off_t size;
    int isDir;
    char *name;
} info;

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    info map[];
} list;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *path = argv[1];
    list lst;
    lst.count = 0;
    struct dirent *dirInfo;
    DIR *dir;
    char *pathName = NULL;
    if(path == NULL)
    {
        path = ".";
    }
    if((dir = opendir(path))  == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n","Ошибка при открытии директории");
        return -1;
    }
    while(dirInfo = readdir(dir))
    {
        if(dirInfo->d_ino)
        {
            struct stat fileInfo;
            pathName = (char *) realloc(pathName, (sizeof(path) + sizeof(char) + sizeof(dirInfo->d_name)));
            strcpy(pathName, path);
            strcat(pathName, "/");
            strcat(pathName, dirInfo->d_name);
            if(lstat(pathName, &fileInfo) == 0) //Второй проход цикла, меняются данные в lst.map[0] (isDir и name)
            {
                if(S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode) || S_ISREG(fileInfo.st_mode))
                {
                    lst.map[lst.count].name = NULL;
                    lst.map[lst.count].name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(dirInfo->d_name));
                    strncpy(lst.map[lst.count].name, dirInfo->d_name,strlen(dirInfo->d_name));
                    lst.map[lst.count].size = fileInfo.st_size;
                    lst.map[lst.count].isDir = S_ISREG(fileInfo.st_mode);
                    lst.count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n","Done");
    for(int i = 0; i < lst.count; i++)
    {
        printf("%ld\t%s\n",lst.map[i].size,lst.map[i].name);
        free(lst.map[i].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Linux mint, GCC. Программа должна быть написана с использованием системных вызовов Linux

Comment: в с нет автоматически увеличивающихся массивов. поэтому, если объявили что то в виде `info map[]`, то память выделять нужно ручками.

Comment: Ещё, например, вместо `strlen(path)` почему-то `sizeof(path)`. И при выделении памяти для строки нужно учитывать нулевой байт. Вообще у вас же Linux, почему бы не использовать valgrind.

Comment: достаточно компилировать вот так `gcc main.c  -fsanitize=address -ggdb` и не нужно никаких valgrind'ов

Comment: Спасибо, действительно глупый косяк с map[]. А по поводу valgrind не знал. Буду иметь ввиду на будущее, спасибо